# A pattern about collection accessor transformation

Tags: java, design-patterns

How to call this pattern, and is there any existing apache-commons utility for this:

```
class Person {
    String getName();
}

List<Person> persons = ...;

// create a dynamic bean on the fly, which can be used as:
Object personXxxx = transformListOfBeans(Person.class, persons);
// so each of the bean properties now returns the list of the original property:
List<String> personNames = personXxxx.name;

// i.e. the transformation creates a new "type":
class PersonXxxx {
    List<String> getName();
}
```

How to call this kind of transformation? A proxy should keep the method signatures. So it is not a proxy, neither decorator.

Well, I can simply rename the generated property names to plural form, like:

```
personXxxx.names
```

This is no problem. I want to know if such pattern was already known so I don't have to choose the appropriate words myself.

Comment: I think the explanation is not enough. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I think he wants a way to get NOT a List of Person, but a List of their names, a List of their ages etc.  I don't know of a good, general way to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a bean or class on the fly?

Comment: @gurung: I'd prefer to create a Map, with the key "name", "age", etc. But this is just an implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a tool exists for this.
You have to code it :

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(persons.size());
for (Person person : persons) {
    names.add(person.getName());
}
```

Maybe you can use introspection to be more generic, but code is really simple.

Comment: Yes, code is simple. I want to get a good word for `Xxxx`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any name. This does not solve any king of problem, so it's not a pattern : patterns were issued from problems.

Comment: It does. So you won't have to collect the list each time. Just transform it and you get all. You can show the list of person.name in an Html Listbox without create and fill the list yourself. In JSP you always foreach and println, but in JSF you need a `List<String>` to bind with the `<h:selectOneListBox>`.

Comment: yes, but you don't have to store it in an object and try to give a name to this object. You just have to store it in a variable and pass the variable to the view. Put the list of names in a cache if you need optimization.

Comment: No, I didn't try to store it. The generated accessor can create the list of the specific property on demand. Well, this question is not about caching and optimization...

Comment: Trying to fit everything as a design pattern is a disease.  Design patterns are only useful for high-level design... for problems that have cropped up frequently enough that developers made some new vocabulary to save time by not having to re-explain the solution pattern.

Comment: @toto2: Correct. But I want to pick a good word here. I'm not a native english speaker. Well, why not make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a pattern as such, but guava provides a simple way of transforming a collection of one to another. For the example:

```
List<Person> persons = ...;
Iterable<String> names = Iterables.transform(persons, new Function<Person, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Person person) {
        return person.getName();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice.  I'd probably make some static methods or an enum for most of the common cases.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to declare an interface for all the methods, e.g. (leading I for clarity) INamable, IAgeable, ISexable etc.  Cast `the List<Person> to List<ISomething>.`  Obviously this has issues.